# Can I make a template style external?

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

In [Google Polymer lesson 1](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html), they have an example that includes an inline stylesheet.
I'd like to move it to a css file, but the style is inside a template tag.
To make matters worse, it says it's

> Used inside a shadow DOM tree, the :host pseudo-class matches the
>   element that hosts the tree. In this case, it matches the 
>   element.

Q: Can I move this style to a css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the elements that are part of a custom elements Shadow DOM you have to use the `::shadow` selector, or `/deep/` selector if you want to select elements regardless how many levels deep they sit inside of Shadow DOM.

So from the outside, you would style a `p` element that's inside `x-foo`'s Shadow DOM like this:

```
x-foo::shadow p {

}
```

You can read about all that stuff here: http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html

Comment: Hmmm.. It says "If you’re feeling loco"... I don't know.  It's just an automatic reaction for me to put my styles in external files. Is it ok to link to it from within the imported html?

Comment: A seems like I misunderstood your question. So the answer is YES! You can just put your styles into an external file here's how: https://github.com/IonicWebComponents/ion-button/blob/master/ion-button.html#L23

Comment: Yet you still got the check mark!  No hard feelings though ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you download the seed element from [this page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/reusableelements.html) (or just look at the listed contents), you'll see that it uses an external css file.  You can examine the element html to see how it is used, but it's very simple:

```
<polymer-element name="seed-element" attributes="notitle author">

  <template>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="seed-element.css" />

    <h1>Hello from seed-element</h1>
    <content></content>

  </template>
  <script>

    Polymer('seed-element', {
      //...
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then in seed-element.css by default you have the following:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

The way I understand it (in my limited knowledge) is that if you were to rename seed-element to my-element, this would be the same as doing

```
my-element {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: `:host` is a selector that specifies the `shadowRoot` host, which is in case of Polymer elements with `<template>` definition the element itself.

Comment: To summarize: styles in an external stylesheet that are `link`ed to from inside a Polymer element will apply the same as if they were in an inline style tag.

Comment: Using Polymer 1.6.1, added ```link``` inside ```template``` which is inside ```dom-module```... and styles are NOT scoped.

Comment: External stylesheets [are deprecated](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#external-stylesheets) for v1.